# Input string slicing and inserting characters

Tags: python

"Write a program that turns a string containing a 10 digit telephone number such as "415551212" into a more readable string with parentheses and a dash, like this: (415)555-1212."

The easiest way of doing this, anyone? I got an idea but I think I'm overthinking the problem.

*Disclaimer:*
I'm not here to copy your code and forget it...
I want to see best ways of doing this so I can learn and apply these ways in the future.

Comment: Tell us about that idea of yours ;-)

Comment: Here's an example of what I was thinking about: string = '123456789'
 
print(string[:4]+'...'+string[5:])

Comment: is there a better way of doing this? Or is this a good one

Comment: Please see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for how to ask a good question. This one gets a "do my homework for me" vibe

Comment: @Tomerikoo what are you talking about I'm here to learn...

Comment: @XA1NE For future reference, the best way to convince people you're not trying to just get someone to do your work for you is to show what you've tried and describe how exactly it doesn't meet your needs. People around here are generally pretty happy to help people, but many will only put as much effort in as you've shown that you've put in yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try simple string formatting with the appropriate slices:

```
tel = "415551212" 
"({}){}-{}".format(tel[:3], tel[3:6], tel[6:])
# '(415)551-212'
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Here's my code: PHONE_NR = input('Input your number: ')
fixedPhone = ('('+PHONE_NR[0:3]+')'+PHONE_NR[3:5]+'-'+PHONE_NR[5:9])

Comment: Or with an f-string: `f'({tel[:3]}){tel[3:6]}-{tel[6:]}'`

Answer (score 0):

Import the `re` library for making a Regex. Then use this statement:

```
print('(%s)%s-%s' % tuple(re.findall(r'\d{4}$|\d{3}', '4155551212')))
```

Output:

```
(415)555-1212
```